# How to get json decode array results using php and html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm new in php. I make below code to get facebook album photos fbid.
Its working and showing me FBID but showing me in array.

Array results has this ID:  `[id] => 100923570620044` and Time: `[created_time] => 2017-08-04T12:43:02+0000`

I wants to show only FBID on html code...

such as:

`<div style="background:black;color:white;">ID: 100923570620044 </div>`

Or,

```
<a href="100923570620044">Here</a>
```

I tried it... But i can't do it.

My Code:

```
<?php
$token="FACEBOOK ACCESS TOKEN";
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/100922980620103/photos?fields=id&access_token=$token");
echo "<pre>";
print_r( json_decode($data, true) );
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

How to i get only ID on html code. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: you understand, what i wants?

Comment: $responsedata= json_decode($data, true);
echo $responsedata['id'];

Comment: not showing.. its blank

Comment: Try this code:

`<?php
    $token="FACEBOOK ACCESS TOKEN";
 $data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/100922980620103/photos?fields=id&access_token=$token");
    $json = json_decode($data);
    echo $json->id; //get id
 echo $json->created_time; //created time
?>`

Comment: nothing to showing

Comment: not showing... blank